# Using the same command twice but getting a differrent response if the user is in the list

Tags: python, bots, twitch

I'm currently creating a bot for twitch in python. 
If a user types `!start` I want the output `Tracking time`, and if the SAME USER again types `start` I want the output `Already tracking time`. 
I have tried this:

```
people = []
if "!start" in message:
    sendMessage(s, "Now recording your time in chat.")
    print(user.title() + " is now tracking time.")
    people.append(user)
    print(", ".join(people))

    if user in people and "start" in message:
        sendMessage(s, "Worked")
```

The current output I am getting when I type "!start" in chat is: `Tracking time.` ~new line~ `Already tracking time.`

Comment: Can you show more from your code? where is the input coming from?

Comment: You write "...if the user **again** types start". Did you mean "!start"? For instance, if I'm using your bot, the first time I say "!start" the bot should respond "Now recording your time.", and the second time I say "!start" it should respond "Already tracking time."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you don't check if `user` is already being tracked until the end of your case, after already having sent "Now recording your time in chat". You need to perform that check earlier. Something along these lines might work for you:

```
people = []
if "!start" in message:
    if user in people:
        sendMessage(s, "Already tracking time")
    else:
        sendMessage(s, "Now recording your time in chat.")
        print(user.title() + " is now tracking time.")
        people.append(user)
        print(", ".join(people))
```

Having developed bots in Python a while back (with poor coding practices), I'm guessing that this `if` block is one of many in a large `handle_message` function. If that's the case, you most likely want to move `people = []` out of that function so it doesn't get reinitialised on each received message.

---

To demonstrate this solution using a mock implementation of `sendMessage`:

```
def sendMessage(message):
    print('Bot responds: {}'.format(message))

people = []

def handle_message(user, message):
    print('{} says: {}'.format(user, message))
    if "!start" in message:
        if user in people:
            sendMessage("Already tracking time")
        else:
            sendMessage("Now recording your time in chat.")
            print(user.title() + " is now tracking time.")
            people.append(user)
            print(", ".join(people))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(2):
        handle_message("John", "!start")
```

**Output**

```
John says: !start
Bot responds: Now recording your time in chat.
John is now tracking time.
John
John says: !start
Bot responds: Already tracking time
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#people = []
people = {}
if "!start" in message:
    sendMessage(s, "Now recording your time in chat.")
    print(user.title() + " is now tracking time.")
    people[user] = ['Already Tracking Time']
    print(", ".join(people))

    if user in people and "start" in message:
        sendMessage(people[user][0], "Worked") # In case you want to send a different message for different command then you just have to append to the user in this dictionary and reference the correct subscript in the list.
```

Hope this helps, else please provide some more info on the question and the complete code.

Comment: How would this help? I agree that it probably makes more sense to use a set instead of a list, but this doesn't address OP's main concern that the bot should respond differently if a user repeats "!start" while already being tracked.

Comment: If the user is already in the "people" dictionary then it sends the message "Already Tracking Time" which is what the poster wanted to do I believe. Notice that the bot prints "Already Tracking" only if "start" is pressed again not if "!start" is pressed again

Comment: If *any* user says "!start", the bot will respond "Now recording your time in chat." *regardless* of whether that user is already being tracked or not. And what is `people[user] = ['Already Tracking Time']` supposed to do?

Comment: Oh, hold on. You raise a good point that I'll need clarification on from OP. I'll lift the downvote as I'm not sure what OP wants.

Comment: To quote the question "If a user types '!start' I want the output Tracking time, and if the SAME USER again types 'start' I want the output Already tracking time" I don't think the understanding is correct

Comment: But you do realise your code will keep causing the bot to respond "Now recording your time in chat." even if the bot already is?

Comment: I realized that the indentation in my answer was off from the original code posted, just rectified it. Also I think the set is essential because as the number of users grow it will be a lot better to use it rather than a list which has a O(N) lookup time. The general idea is to use the set and store a list of values, and the correct value for a given situation can be printed by choosing the appropriate subscript for the corresponding item from the list.